# find and replace strings

Tags: java

I am trying to find and replace strings. Below is what I have sofar. 
I am troubled on how to force all the changes to show in one line as showed below.

```
Strings source = "parameter='1010',parameter="1011",parameter="1012" ";
Expected result = "parameter='1013',parameter="1015",parameter="1009" ";


Strings fin1 = "1010";

Strings fin2 = "1011";

Strings fin3 = "1012";

Strings rpl1 = "1013";

Strings rpl1 = "1015";

Strings rp21 = "1009";

Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(fin1);
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(fin2);
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile(fin3);

Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(source);  
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(source); 
Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(source);

String output1  = matcher1 .replaceAll(rpl1);
String output2  = matcher2 .replaceAll(rpl2);
String output3  = matcher3 .replaceAll(rpl3);
```

thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by _"force all the changes to show in one line?"_

Comment: @Matt: I imagine OP means they want all three replacements applied to the same string.  In the current code, OP gets three different output strings - `output1`, `output2`, `output3`, each with one of the three replacements separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replaceAll(..)` method defined on `String`:

```
String source = "parameter='1010',parameter='1011',parameter='1012' ";
source = source.replaceAll("1010", "1013");
source = source.replaceAll("1011", "1015");
source = source.replaceAll("1012", "1009");
```

or more succinctly:

```
source = source.replaceAll("1010", "1013").replaceAll("1011", "1015").replaceAll("1012", "1009");
```

Note that the first parameter of `replaceAll(..)` is treated as a regular expression as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do the following:

```
String result=source.replaceAll(fin1,rpl1).replaceAll(fin12,rpl2).replaceAll(fin3,rpll);
```

> An invocation of this method of the
>   form str.replaceAll(regex, repl)
>   yields exactly the same result as the
>   expression 
>   Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)

So you don't have to do all the intermediate compilation of regex etc.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "parameter='1010',parameter='1011',parameter='1012' ";

        String fin1 = "1010";
        String fin2 = "1011";
        String fin3 = "1012";

        String rpl1 = "1013";
        String rpl2 = "1015";
        String rpl3 = "1009";

        source = source.replaceAll(fin1, rpl1).replaceAll(fin2, rpl2).replaceAll(fin3, rpl3);

        System.out.println("Result: " + source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this took care of my problem. Thank you!